# command: how to avoid "Press ENTER or type command to continue"

Tags: vimscript

In my `.vimrc`, I set a shortcut:

```
command Q call delete('.ycm_extra_conf.py')|call delete('.tags')|qa
```

Now I can type `:Q` + `[enter]` to delete the two files and quit all plugins and vim.

However, if I forget to save before `:Q` + `[enter]`, I will get the message as below:

[image]

I have to type a `[enter]` because of the `Press ENTER or type command to continue`.

How could I avoid this message so that I don't need to type a `[enter]` anymore?

Comment: do you have `:set hidden`? I think this will solve your issue and should be set anyway. It's a save setting.

Comment: @Naumann  It doesn't work.

Comment: Why not `wqa` or `wall|qa` or some variant? It might have some unexpected effects if you edited a temp file you never intended to save though

Comment: What do you want to reach? Quit Vim without saving anything or save anything and exit. Please update question.

Comment: @Ralf  just like the common action of vim: if you type `:q` without saving, an error will popup but without `Press ENTER or type command to continue` so you don't need to type an `[enter]'.

Comment: You could directly enter `:wq`. Vim already changed to the buffer that needs saving.  No need to press `<enter>` first. If you have another file with changes, you will get the same prompt again. Then again enter `:wq`. Btw: `:x` is the same as `:wq`, but saves a key press.

Comment: it seems that 'qa' will generate this message. I can't modify it.

Comment: Yes, and the message is absolutely valid. You want to exit Vim and you have unsaved files. It's the job of the editor to inform you about that. You could also use `:qa!`, to just quit without saving anything. Although I would not recommend this in your mapping,

Comment: What the OP probably means is, what I describe as follows: If you increase the height of your command window, say to 5 lines (via mouse, or `:set cmdheigt=5`), and issue then `:qa` for a buffer with unsaved content, then you get this `Press ENTER ...` prompt, although it is not necessary. I have seen also other cases besides `:qa` with this behavior. Of course, this prompt is necessary for scrollable output, but not when everything fits in the command window.